# Accessing a HTTPS server using old ciphers

Tags: ssl, https, tls

I was looking around the EWS of my HP printer and I accidentally set a old cipher and I can't access anymore, I'm always getting `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` from chrome.

Any browser settings I need to set to get access to this https server again? I test Chrome, Firefox, Edge, iexplore and got nothing.

I check via `nmap` the ciphers available to access the https server:

```
gabriel@pc:~$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 192.168.223.1
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org )
Nmap scan report for 192.168.223.1
Host is up (0.045s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|   TLSv1.1: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|_  least strength: C

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.44 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A less elegant solution would be to find an old linux distro and install it (possibly as a VM), then use the browser from that to access your printer.

Old distros are available from: https://soft.lafibre.info/

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try that.

Comment: I finally got it.  I tried using Windows 7 SP1 in a VM, without access to Internet. The Internet Explorer accessed the website normally xD